# Android - Library Project

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

While referencing a project as a library project only some projects are shown in the list, why all the projects are not displayed? How do I recognize that a project is a library project?
and how do I make a normal project as a library project?

Comment: On project right click -> Android -> isLibrary to check/set for project to library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) the list only show library projects, so other projects aren't show in the list.

2) a project is a library project if isLibrary in project => properties => android is checked.

3) just check isLibrary in project => properties => android

Answer (score 2):

You can do like that:

Right click in your project and go to properties.
In Android option you have a box named Library. In this box you can add or remove Libraries that you have in your workspace.